# It is possible to set fields which i want to get in overpass api&

Tags: php, json, openstreetmap, overpass-api

For example. I want to get coordinates of all node buildings in bbox.

PHP

```
$queryBuildings="[out:json];node['building']({$y1},{$x1},{$y2},{$x2});out;";

$data = file_get_contents("http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data={$queryBuildings}")
```

One element from result:

```html
{
  "type": "node",
  "id": 29537155,
  "lat": 54.6744568,
  "lon": -2.1421066,
  "tags": {
    "building": "house",
    "description": "Abandoned (2007). Associate with lead mine workings above it?",
    "name": "Flushiemere House"
  }
}
```

I want to get only lon and lat fields it's possible?

Comment: try json_decode() to parse your code.

Comment: I mean to set sequence of fields in response using overpass-api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [skeleton *print* mode](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Language_Guide#Concise_.28skeleton.29) (`out skel`) which omits all tags, thus being slightly shorter. So your request should become: `[out:json];node['building']({$y1},{$x1},{$y2},{$x2});out skel;`

Currently [csv *output* mode](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#Output_Format_.28out.29) (`[out:csv]`) is the only mode where you can select the fields to be shown.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$data = '{
  "type": "node",
  "id": 29537155,
  "lat": 54.6744568,
  "lon": -2.1421066,
  "tags": {
    "building": "house",
    "description": "Abandoned (2007). Associate with lead mine workings above it?",
    "name": "Flushiemere House"
  }
}';
$test = json_decode($data);

var_dump($test->lon);
```

Answer (score 0):

First use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to parse the response body:

```
$parsed_data = json_decode($data);
```

Then you can access the various fields like so:

```
$lat = $parsed_data->lat;
$lon = $parsed_data->lon;
```